# How do I fix this AuthStateListener issue

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I have two activities: `SignIn` and `SignUp`. Each of them has an AuthStateListener.

The problem is that AuthStateListener from `SignIn` activity gets called when app is in `SignUp` activity and authentication state is changed (Found this when I logged in both listener).

onCreate method of SignIn :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_in);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null && isEmailVerified()) {
                Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Signed In", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                finish();
                startActivity(new Intent(SignIn.this, UserProfile.class));
            } else if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                mAuth.getCurrentUser().sendEmailVerification().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Verification email sent You can sign in once your account is verified.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        mAuth.signOut();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
    });

   ........
}
```

onCreate method of SignUp :

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    .....

    mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
        @Override
        public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth) {
            if (mAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
                verifyEmail();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

What can be done to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want an `AuthStateListener` to be called anymore, you need to unregister it by calling [`removeAuthStateListener`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/FirebaseAuth.html#removeAuthStateListener(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener)).

This means you need to keep track of the listener, so:

```
listener = new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
  ...
}
mAuth.addAuthStateListener(listener);
```

You'd typically do that in the opposite lifecycle event of where you register them. In your case I'd recommend moving the `addAuthStateListener` on `onStart` and then unregister it in `onStop` or in `onPause` with

```
mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(listener)
```

Comment: After reading your answer I created an instance of `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener` and put it like `mAuth.addAuthStateListener(authStateListener);` and `mAuth.removeAuthStateListener(authStateListener);` it is working perfectly but you have mentioned a `listener` object in your first code snippet. I am not understanding what will be the class name of this `listener` object. It will be very helpful for me if you please clarify this.

Comment: Referring to the linked documentation, `listener` is a `FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener`.

Comment: But the problem is that I can't put

`mAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
  ...`
in `listener` because this method is a `void` method and it doesn't return anything.
I think your solution needs little bit correction.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's a mistake in my code. I updated it.