# Unfortunately MyBooks is stopped

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

when I sign up after that I am going on the next activity page that is 
    HomeActivity which is displaying welcome...You are logged in and when I 
    clicked on GO AHEAD button an error is occurring that is Unfortunately 
    MyBooks is stopped. Why is it so? Why is it that error is occurring?
    Is there any mistake in creating Intent..?

This is my HomeActivity.java

```
 package com.example.easylearn;
 import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.widget.Button;

 import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

 public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  Button btngo;
  FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
  private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);
     btngo = findViewById(R.id.go);

     btngo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
         @Override
         public void onClick(View v) {
             Intent intgo = new 
    Intent(HomeActivity.this,BranchActivity.class);
             startActivity(intgo);
         }
     });
    }
    }
```

This is my BranchActivity.java

```
    package com.example.easylearn;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;

public class BranchActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Button CSE;
    Button ME;
    Button Civil;
    Button EE;
    FirebaseAuth mFirebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_branch);

        mFirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        CSE = findViewById(R.id.button);
        ME = findViewById(R.id.button4);
        Civil = findViewById(R.id.button3);
        EE = findViewById(R.id.button5);

        CSE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intCSE = new Intent(BranchActivity.this,YearActivity.class);
                startActivity(intCSE);
            }
        });

        ME.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intME = new Intent(BranchActivity.this,YearActivity.class);
                startActivity(intME);
            }
        });

        EE.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intEE = new Intent(BranchActivity.this,YearActivity.class);
                startActivity(intEE);
            }
        });

        Civil.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intCivil = new 
         Intent(BranchActivity.this,YearActivity.class);
                startActivity(intCivil);
            }
        });
        }

       @Override
       protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
        }
      }
```

Comment: Can you please share the log details

Comment: hey share you log details , i think this is happening because of firebase

Comment: E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.easylearn, PID: 13140
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'void com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth$AuthStateListener.onAuthStateChanged(com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth)' on a null object reference
        at com.google.firebase.auth.zzn.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)

Comment: at com.google.android.gms.internal.firebase_auth.zzj.dispatchMessage(com.google.firebase:firebase-auth@@19.1.0:6)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6946)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1404)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1199)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 13140 SIG: 9
Process 13140 terminated.

Comment: The `mAuthStateListener` is never instantiated and it's null, I suppose(?)

Comment: where? Can you please tell me

Comment: you are adding a null listener mAuthStateListener, and not initializing it and then passing it to  mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're calling:

```
mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(mAuthStateListener);
```

Which means that you're asking Firebase to call methods on the `mAuthStateListener` object when the user's authentication state changes. But you never give `mAuthStateListener` any value in your code, so it's `null`. When the authentication state changes, Firebase tries to call `mAuthStateListener.onAuthStateChanged`, which leads to the error you get.

The solution is to properly implement the auth state change listener, as for example shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55307773). It could be something like this for you:

```
mFirebaseAuth.addAuthStateListener(new FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAuthStateChanged(@NonNull FirebaseAuth auth) {
        if (auth.getCurrentUser() != null) {
            ...
        }
    }
});
```

In which case you don't even need the `private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener mAuthStateListener;` field anymore.